# Cannot query actual values "_blank" with underscore via graphql in Strapi

Tags: graphql, strapi

I create Enumeration values with underscore in Strapi, such as "_blank", "_self", and then query these values via graphql, the returned value is "blank", but if I query the value via RestApi, the returned value is "_blank".

[create enumeration in Strapi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppnKl.png)

How can I query the actual value "_blank" via graphql in Strapi?